# no abre la ventana de print en ngxPrint

Tags: angular

```
   Cannot read property 'open' of undefined at t.print
   
    Angular 9 y "ngx-print": "^1.2.0-beta.5"

   Esto es el print-expensas.componenta.html

    <h1>hola</h1>
     <div id="print-section">
      <span>{{administrador.NOMBRE}}</span>
      <span>{{administrador.DOMICILIO}}</span>
      <span>{{administrador.TELEFONOS}}</span>
      <span>{{administrador.MAIL}}</span>
      <span>{{administrador.NROINSC}}</span>
      <span>{{administrador.SITFISCAL}}</span>
    </div>
    <button printTitle="MyTitle" printSectionId="print-section" ngxPrint>print</button>
```

**Si entiendo bien, ngxPrint necesita un window nuevo, el tema es que he probado con window.open(), con render new window.
A esta altura debe ser algo simple que me estoy perdiendo.
Gracias**

Comment: Deberías de aportar el código que has hecho para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Obtengo estos errores, los pongo por si main.1c441845540833f5620c.js:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined
    at t.print (main.1c441845540833f5620c.js:1)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (main.1c441845540833f5620c.js:1)